# How to handle commands containing "-" in python sh module?

Tags: python, git, sh

I need to [`git-archive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) using Python [`sh module`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh). 
The command is:

```
git archive --format tar HEAD
```

but it seems it's complicated to handle commands containing arguments or `-`. For example `git ls-files` I can't do `git.sh.ls-files`

Comment: Why is this complicated? If you described the exact problem you're seeing, that would make it easier to address.

Comment: cause i can't do `sh.git.ls-files`

Comment: ...but you can do `sh.git('ls-files')`, which is the normal usage mode anyhow.

Comment: good, what about `git archive --format tar`?

Comment: `sh.git('archive', '--format', 'tar')`

Comment: Please write it in answer area, so I Accept it as a correct answer. and THANK YOU!

Comment: ...by the way, I'm of the strong belief that the `sh` module is too clever by half for its own good, and that you should consider sticking closer to `subprocess.Popen()` with `shell=False` -- being, as it is, a thinner layer, it does less that hides the actual operating system calls being run, thus reducing potential for surprise or confusion. Longer, more verbose code, yes -- but also more explicit.

Comment: Sure, but I need a faster and clever solution right now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foo.bar.baz` syntax is intended as a special-case convenience feature; it's not by any means obligatory. If you can't use it, don't. Thus:

```
sh.git('ls-files')
```

This follows for more complex commands as well:

```
sh.git('archive', '--format', 'tar')
```